# NSDate Issue While Creating it from NSString

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have seen many solutions and tried it since last 2 hours.
So i am posting my code.
I am seeing Log everything is fine with NSString that contains a Date.

But when i tried it to convert to NSDate.
It's return and logging null.

**Here is my Code**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

NSString *str = @"2014-10-28 00:00:00 AM";    
NSLog(@"Date %@",str);   ////Showing String Date

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dater = [formatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"Dater %@",dater);     ////Showing null log
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The format does not match the string one.

Comment: the formatter defines a totally different format, have you not spotted it? your input: `"2014-10-28 00:00:00 AM"` and your formatter: `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`. they mismatch.

Comment: yes now i get it.
i am newbee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change with this one:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

to

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Obviously the dateformat doesn't match the format in your date string, because your string contains AM/PM values and the format of your formatter does not.